# Reposition UIView keeping its subview position unchanged

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

How to reposition UIView keeping its subview at same position before reposition. When i move the UIView its subview are also getting moved.How can i avoid that. I just want to move the parent view not its subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that's not how view hierarchy works, unless I am mistaken, there's no way to prevent a subview from moving with its superview.

What you could do is reposition the subview while the superview is moving (but don't animate it) so it gives the illusion that it doesn't move.

The way I'd do it within these restrictions is to get the position of the subview in relation to the superview's superview (convertRect:toView: method) then simply set the frame's origin every time your superview is moving.

Comment: My subview is rotated image view and my parent view is uiview. When i rotate image view it goes out of bounds of uiview so i have to resize the uiview so that image can fit into uiview. But as i am changing my uiview frame image view is also getting shifted.